# Sorting out logic homework with a friend.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

My friend and I were looking over my homework and he pointed out something that he thought was incorrect.

I was to write sentances using logical connectives.

The original sentance was:
    "To get an A in this class, it is necessary for you to get an A on the final exam.

I figured the translation would be:

```
Let p = You get an A in this class.
Let q = You get an A on the final.
q -> p
```

But he figured the correct way to write the sentance would be the inverse:

```
p -> q
```

I agreed, but as I continued in my book I found an example the seemed to confirm what I had originally thought. Could anyone help me sort out who is correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you studied the difference between necessity and sufficiency? Also, what is the example you found that you think confirms what you thought?

Comment: @user170141 No, I haven't. This may be what's got me mixed up. I guess I should look into this.

Comment: @user170141 That you very much. I just read the Wikipedia page on [Necessity and Sufficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) and things are much clearer now.

To get an A on the final is necessary to get an A in the class.
To get an A in the class is a sufficient condition for getting an A on the final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is correct.

To see why, consider the implication $q\implies p$. This states that if you get an A on the final exam, then you get an A in the class. This is clearly not what is meant by the original sentence. The original sentence says instead that you must get an A on the final to get an A in the class. Therefore anyone who receives an A in the class must have received an A on the final exam. This is precisely the meaning of $p \implies q$.

Another way to see how your friend is correct is to remember that the contrapositive of a statement shares its truth value. Thus, if the implication $q \implies p$ is true then so too is its contrapositive $!p \implies !q$. This implication states if you did not get an A in the class, then you did not get an A on the final, which is also clearly not the meaning of the original sentence because while getting an A on the final is necessary it is not a sufficient condition for receiving an A in the course.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is right. Getting an A on the final does not necessarily mean you get an A in class

q does not imply p

but if you got an A in class, then you must've gotten an A on the final

p implies q